# How to add a element to a OrientVertex LinkSet using the Java API

Tags: java, orientdb

Using a SQL statement like this:

```
UPDATE User ADD choices = #16:4 where @rid = #18:3
```

I can add an element to a collection.

How can I accomplish the same using the Java API starting from the OrientVertex #18:3 of the User?

Should I navigate using getRecord() of OrientVertex?
What's the Java class for a Collection field and how to access it?

Thank you for any clarification!

Note : Inner class are OTrackedSet, OTrackedList and OTrackedMap.

Answer (score 0):

this code should work

```
OrientGraph g=new OrientGraph(currentPath); 
OrientVertex v =  g.getVertex("#18:3");
OrientElementIterable<OrientVertex> choices=v.getProperty("choices");
Iterator<OrientVertex> it=choices.iterator();
List<OIdentifiable> linklist = new ArrayList<OIdentifiable>();
while(it.hasNext()){
   OrientVertex ve= it.next();
   linklist.add(ve);
}
OrientVertex vertex =  g.getVertex("#16:4");
linklist.add(vertex);
v.setProperty("choices",linklist);
```

Comment: My idea is to avoid to use SQL query but going only by the structure. Your solution should work but do you think we can do more compact? Thank you @alessandro-rota

Comment: I hope to see a much easier solution for the API but it's validated. Thanks Alessandro.